# Is there a way to go up 10 rows from a known value of id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

For instance:

In a table => `mytable` sorted by `Salary` (so, the ids won't be in order),

if I knew the `Id` of an employee (say, `Id=75`), is there any way that I could start selecting **10** rows ***UP*** from that particular `Id (Id=75)` to the **next** 10, thereby ending just above `Id=75`; in mysql?

**Edit (more information):**

I was planning on using this for a `previous` & `next` button for a sorted table.

Sorted table eg:

```
Id=2  | Salary=150K
Id=3  | Salary=100K
Id=8  | Salary=95K
Id=25 | Salary=92K
Id=18 | Salary=90K
Id=35 | Salary=85K
Id=29 | Salary=80K
Id=53 | Salary=75K
Id=50 | Salary=70K
Id=93 | Salary=50K
Id=75 | Salary=45K <----
```

now, `75 was the 1st Id in the second page`, so, in the `previous button`, I'll have:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id > 75 ORDER BY Salary ASC
```

which gives me the rows for Ids => `93 to 2`, **BUT**, that'll be in the **reverse order** which messes up my `previous`& `next` buttons.

Hence my question, and this answer by `Hanky Panky` modified to:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id > 75 ORDER BY Salary ASC LIMIT 10) 
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

is kind of exactly what I had in mind(i.e, `getting the ASC list and then ORDERing it by DESC`). But I get this error when trying it out:

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.
```

**Edit (mistake):**

Right, That was just a dumb thing to try, it'll always look for id's greater than 75 in INT value `> 75` and then sort according to the salary within those returned Id's, which just messes up everything else. Switching to sort by Salary.

**Edit (solution):**

Adding a alias (`t1`) to one of them fixes it.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Salary > 45000 ORDER BY Salary ASC LIMIT 10) t1 
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

To display it in the `High -> Low` order

Comment: Can you post an example along with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is understandable but contradictory.

> is there any way that I could start selecting 10 rows UP from that particular id (id=75) to the next 10, thereby ending at id=75

If you start at 75 and go UP 10, how can you end at 75?  If you want 10 rows above 75 you could do

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id > 75 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```

If you want 10 rows below 75 you can do

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id <= 75 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

If you want these 10 rows in Ascending order still, you can do

```
   SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id <= 75 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
   ) tempAlias ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say 'ending just above 75', 75 not included.

Comment: It was as simple as that in the end (3rd suggestion: dual sorting in a single query). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

May be this one your are asking about

```
SELECT * FROM usersTabLE WHERE id > 75 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

SELECT * FROM bill LIMIT 5,10; #Retrieve row 6-15

SELECT * FROM bill LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615; #all rows

SELECT * FROM bill LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows

select *from product limit 10,20;

--it will leave initial 10 records(rows) and it will show from 11th row to 20th row of bill table

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE id <= 75 LIMIT 10
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE id > 75 LIMIT 10
```

depends on which way you want to go